# CE 1.7.0.2 / After SUPEE-6788 / "Admin > Newsletter > Newsletter queue" results in 404

Tags: admin, ce-1.7.0.2, newsletter, supee-6788

Since I applied the SUPEE-6788 patch to my CE 1.7.0.2 Magento installation, I can't access anymore the page of the admin "Newsletter > Newsletter queue". It results in a 404 error.
The admin URL of that page is the following:
http://domain.com/shop/index.php/admin/newsletter_queue/index/

I also fixed all other blocks & extension with the SUPEE-6788 Developer Toolbox (https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox), but it cannot fix this specific problem.

Thx for your help, I cant send newsletters anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved my problem, it was linked to an old version of the Tentura Newsletter Groups (http://shop.tentura.eu/magento-extensions/newsletter-groups.html). I updated the files with the last version and everything's running fine again.

To find that out, I modified the file

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php

Around line 385, function getControllerFileName, I added

> var_dump($file);

Just before the "return $file;"
Then I could figure out what file was missing when I tried to access the page that was givig the 404 error.